# prpblem to show object in chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, object

i have to show one or more pdf-docs in a part of a website. in all browsers my code still works - only chrome does not show the file.

here is the code-snip i use (the css class is a flex-construct only):

```
    <div class="aufinfo_item_pdf" data-id="<%$image->get_id()%>">
      <object class="aufinfo_item_pdf_obj" data="/company_images/article/<%$image->get_id()%>" type="application/pdf">
        <p>not possible to show - download at: ... link</p>
      </object>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is that PHP? Maybe you need to add semicolon at the end like this: `<%$image->get_id();%>`

Comment: the vars are part of smarty - but not part of the problem - replace it with 0815.pdf or 4711.pdf or whatever :)